# String To int [] in java

Tags: java

```
String str = "1,2,3,4";

int[] test= new int [ 4 ];
```

I need to get only the int values (numbers) from **str** and put them to **test** array and ignore the **","**

the test array should be like that

```
test[]={1,2,3,4}
```

Comment: `split()` method is for this purpose.

Comment: Have you tried something?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first split the String with the method `split()`, and afterwards convert the strings into integers.

```
String str = "1,2,3,4";
String strs[] = str.split(",");
int ints[] = new int[strs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++)
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get numbers from str
String[] values = str.split(",");
int index = 0;
for(String value : values){
   // converting string to int and adding it to test
   test[index++] = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to split your String (the delimiter is "," in your case):

```
  String delimiter=","
  String s="1,2,3";
  String[] ss=s.split(delimiter);
```

After this, get the String elements (ss[i]) into an int array:

```
  int si[] = new int[3];
  for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++){

       System.out.println(ss[i]);
       si[i]=Integer.parseInt(ss[i]);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first split the String with the method split(",") with proper delimiter (here is ","). After that you need to convert the strings into integers and need to store it to some int array. Below is the sample codes.

```
    String str = "1,2,3,4";
    String strArray[] = str.split(",");
    int [ ] test= new int [ strArray.length ];

    int i = 0;
    for(String value: strArray) {
     test[i] = Integer.parseInt(value);// Converting the String value into integer and store that value into integer array 
    i++;
    }
```